# How to say: "screwed it up"

Tags: word-choice, word-requests

How can I express that someone "screwed [something] up?"  For example:

"They really screwed up the code with the last changes they made"

"I gave him one little task and he still managed to screw it up"

"I can't believe I screwed that up."

I would like it to not be vulgar, and as in the English, it is a casual/informal expression that might be used between colleagues or friends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Screw up" is a slang for "to blunder"

[搞砸](http://www.wordreference.com/zhen/%E6%90%9E%E7%A0%B8) /gǎo zá/ : blunder

[弄糟](http://www.wordreference.com/zhen/%E5%BC%84%E7%B3%9F) /nòng zāo/ : blunder ; mess up

> *How can I express that someone "screwed [something] up?"*

他把事情搞砸了

他把事情弄糟了

> [砸](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/2701/)
>
> : break; smash; shatter
>
> : [slang] fail; fall through; flop

Comment: One could also use 弄砸; it takes one character from each of the examples above.

Answer (score 0):

> screw up: 使成螺旋状；挤成一团弄糟，搞乱，弄乱，弄糟：
>
> to screw up something
>
> 把某事搞得一团糟

Dictionary definition above can help you. Basically, screw up: 把...搞砸了; 把...搞糟;etc; For example,

> I can't believe I screwed that up: 很难想象我(竟然)把那件事情搞砸了.

Comment: I think it is 搞砸  /gǎo zá/ ; not  搞杂 (搞雜) /gǎo zá/

Comment: @TangHo, 搞砸 looks more correct, but I think 搞杂 is also grammatically correct. It's because 搞xxx is a common phrase. E.g. 搞坏了，搞糟了，搞好了, 搞乱了. So, 搞杂了 can mean 把...搞得很复杂 or 把...搞得很杂乱.  搞杂了 is more like *mess up*, while 搞砸了 is more like *screw up*. I am not sure how much difference between *mess up* and *screw up* in English. So, I will edit my answer to make it 搞砸了.